# Drupal: Upgrade Node strategy

Tags: drupal

I effectively want two nodes:

1. Normal Node
2. Premium Node

The only difference will be that the premium node can take more images and a few other features. What is the best strategy to go about this?

1. have two distinct nodes with the differences
2. have one nodes and somehow find a to apply an UPGRADED attribute to it?

I would prefer (b), as I want users to be able to upgrade nodes. And migrating a normal node to a premium node will be very difficult.

Any idea how I can accomplish b?

Comment: Is there a possibility of nodes being downgraded, but later upgraded again? That is, would there be cases where someone would have a premium node with the extra stuff, go back to normal, but then go back to premium and expect their stuff to still be there?

Comment: In this scenario, clients will never downgrade. But who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two different content types (CCK), and either write custom code to translate between the two or use a module like [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) (in order to upgrade a node); it might be complicated at first, but you would have the advantage of being able to apply all of your restrictions (allowed image count, permissions etc) on a per-content type basis.

Here is an excerpt from the Node Convert project page:

> ... adds a menu tab "Convert" on the node view page, i.e. node/1/convert, which gives the ability to convert the node from its current node type to another node type. The module provides the means to transfer all the field values of the current node type into fields on the destination node type, or discard them.
>
> The module integrates with Actions, Rules, Views Bulk Operations and Admin Views nicely. It has support for exporting templates into Features using CTools Exportables. It also provides a hook that enables developers to execute additional code on conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to implement (b) as two different input filters - one for non-upgraded and one for upgraded. Then "upgrading" the node would be as simple as changing the input filter applied to its contents.

Comment: But how do I limit users from uploading only 4 photos, instead of unlimited. That is one of the differences between a normal node and an upgraded one.

Comment: The filter is passed the complete text of the node - your filter function and check through the text and see if more than 4 images are included. Restrictions on the actual # of images that could be *uploaded* to the server would probably need to be handled in whatever module you're using to upload the images.

Comment: This is not so easy if using CCK to upload the files. Most likely some sort of cck integration would be needed to do this kind of thing which get quite complicated very fast.